# Is ElasticSearch(lucene) segment a must while writing a doc onto disk?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm wondering if a Lucene segment is required while writing a doc to disk.
Here is the brief procedure how a doc goes into disk from ElasticSearch
Firstly, an ElasticSearch document is written into in-memory cache (refer to LSM-tree memTable)
Secondly, a bunch of documents are refreshed to page cache (every 1s) as an immutable Lucene segment (refer to LSM-tree immutable memTable)
Eventually, that segment will be "fsync" onto a disk.

It seems that we can totally bypass the "page cache" part, that's to say that at the first step, when we want to create a doc in the in-memory buffer, elasticsearch creates a segment for it. Then if we want to update that doc, elasticSearch creates another segment for the updated doc.
Now we have 2 segments in total. After 1 second these two segments will be merged and refreshed on the disk.

Do you know what advantage of Lucene segment is here?

Answer (score 0):

The page cache is designed to minimize disk I/O by storing data in physical memory that would otherwise require disk access.
Caches supports different strategies generally, no-write, write-througn cache and write-back. Page cache is a kind of write-back strategy. Pages are flushed into disk periodically.
This mechanism accelerate data accessand reduce the number of I/O.
Lucene writes page cache to improve the system I/O throughput.
Of course page cache cost more memory and may lose data in cache.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your proposal would behave similarly to setting [`refresh=true` on the Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) to build a segment immediately for the upsert.

Unfortunately the documentation also states:

> `true` creates less efficient indexes constructs (tiny segments) that must later be merged into more efficient index constructs (larger segments). Meaning that the cost of `true` is paid at index time to create the tiny segment, at search time to search the tiny segment, and at merge time to make the larger segments.

Depending on your use case, the cost at search time is likely to be the most significant of the three "costs" mentioned. Elasticsearch has to read all segments when searching, and when segments only contain one document each this becomes equivalent to brute force search.

Comment: FWIW new documents are not available for search before refresh runs (even though they are available by _id with something like `GET my-index-000001/_doc/0`), so what you call a "in-memory cache" is more like a write buffer or a write ahead log when it comes to search.